# Custom accessor is much slower than automatic in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am trying to hunt down a strange thing that I am seeing in Core Data. I've created a sample project showing the issue here - https://github.com/mattjgalloway/CocoaBugs/tree/master/CoreDataSlowSetters

I have two different attributes on a Core Data modelled object. One uses the dynamically created setter. One uses a custom setter which does nothing more than this:

```
- (void)setCustom:(NSString *)custom {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"custom"];
    [self setPrimitiveCustom:custom];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"custom"];
}
```

If I instrument using each setter, I find that the custom one is much slower (~3x slower) than the automatic one.

In that sample project I am doing the following tight-loop to show the issue:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    Entity *entity = [Entity insertInManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    entity.generic = @"something"; ///< Time profiler shows 6.3% time here
    entity.custom = @"something"; ///< Time profiler shows 19.9% time here
}
```

[Note: I'm using mogenerator, hence the `insertInManagedObjectContext:` helper method.]

Has anyone else seen this issue? I've tried hunting down what the automatically generated accessor does and it seems not much more than my custom accessor.

Am I just out of luck and if you implement the accessor yourself then it will just be a *lot* slower?

I haven't filed a radar on it yet, but I will do soon.

Comment: `willChangeValueForKey:` seems to be the culprit. I made a similar test (with a OS X command-line tool), and 80% of `setCustom:` was spent in `willChangeValueForKey:`. - But I have no idea why that happens or how to solve it. (But the Core Data Programming Guide explicitly mentions that the automatic accessors are optimized.)

Comment: That's a very interesting question. Waiting for Marcus Zarra or Martin R answers. :-)

Comment: @MartinR yes indeed. But you have to call that, as per Apple docs. The dynamically generated one doesn't call `willChangeValueForKey:` directly. It calls a C function which is called something like `_PF_xxx_WillChangeValueForKeyIndex` (haven't got the actual symbol name to hand) inside a copy of `_sharedImpl_setVfk_core` which is created for each dynamic setter. Odd that it's *that* much slower. I'm creating a tonne of objects in an app you see, where I'm seeing custom accessors make a huge difference to overall time to import a data set.

Comment: My guess is that the lookup from the `@"custom"` string to whatever it needs inter ally (some index?) is super-super-slow.

Comment: It seems that the generated and the custom setter are almost equally fast if you actually register an observer for both properties. That could mean that the generated setter is optimized for the case of no observers.

Comment: @MartinR very interesting... I didn't try that. It certainly is possible.

Comment: @MartinR Yeh I see what you mean! That's annoying then... I guess we're just stuck with it. Worth knowing!

Comment: @MartinR Could you explain better this sentence? *It seems that the generated and the custom setter are almost equally fast if you actually register an observer for both properties. That could mean that the generated setter is optimized for the case of no observers.* I would just going deep on this.

Comment: @flexaddicted what it means is that if you register an observer for `custom` and `generic` in my sample project, then profile, you'll see that the same amount of time is set in each accessor. Therefore it looks like the dynamically generated setter (i.e. no custom setter) is optimised to know when there are no observers.

Comment: Ok I see. So in your previous profiling you registered only the custom accessor. True? When you mean observer I suppose a fetched results controller. Other examples?

Comment: I registered neither. Then I registered both. When both are registered the setters are the same speed.

Comment: No it means register KVO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe there is a point in filing a radar.  As Martin pointed out, there is undoubtable some optimizations going on with the generated accessors.

This follows the path that Apple has been stressing lately, don't create custom accessors.  Since accessors should only be accessing their properties there is no reason to create custom ones anymore.  Any logic that you *think* you want to put into the accessor should go somewhere else.

Now you have math to back up that rule :)

Comment: Yes, I agree now. Especially since we now know it's due to the apparent optimisation going on in the generated accessor. I've now changed my pattern to not require the custom accessor. Thanks for reading & giving advice!